# What does "no integrality gap" imply?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, approximation-algorithms, optimization, linear-programming, integrality-gap

I'm currently working on a linear time heuristic for the rectangle decomposition of a binary matrix. This problem has a polynomial time solution, which in our case is too slow for large-scale processing. I devised a linear time heuristic and I would like to characterize its approximation ratio and  the problem is that I'm not familiar with approximations algorithms.

In [this paper](http://www.math.uni-rostock.de/~kalinowski/papers/dual_rectangle_segmentation.pdf), Kalinowski proved that there is no integrality gap for this problem. What consequences does this result have? Does it mean that is impossible to design an approximation algorithm?

Comment: This just means that the optimal objective values of the integer program and its LP relaxation are the same.

Comment: Thank you, does this means that I cannot deduce anything regarding the feasability of an approximation algorithm ?

Comment: you can deduce that solving the LP solves the problem, so it gives an algorithm (but definitely not a linear time one)

Comment: BTW, in terms of simple approximations, the following uses at most $\log n$ factor more rectangles than necessary: at each step choose the rectangle contained in the support of the matrix that covers the most 1's. this is just the greedy approximation for [set cover](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~shuchi/courses/787-F07/scribe-notes/lecture02.pdf)

Comment: The paper is indeed very interesting for the newcomer that I am. Since my linear time algorithm follows a greedy approach it is a good example on how to set up  upper bounds. Btw I finally understood what integrality means. Thanks a lot Sasho.